# How to get emails from website, sent from host with fetch, to not show up as spam

Tags: email, gmail, spam, pop3

Any email that is sent through my website, from a contact form or other source, is sent into my spam folder in my gmail account. I am currently fetching the emails sent with pop3.

I click on the "Not Spam" button every time, but it does not help in any way. Also I just tried setting a filter to help with this, however the issue is still present.

The email is always from a different sender, but it always comes from my host, ie: gatorxxxxx@hostgator.com. This is the email address I put in the filter. I included it in the 'From' and 'has the words' option.

Does this take time to kick in or what else should I try?

```
$name       = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_name'], ENT_QUOTES));
$email      = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_email']));
$phone      = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_phone']));
$message    = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_message'], ENT_QUOTES));
$email_from = "contact@xxx.com";

if($hasError !== true) {
    $to = "contact@xxx.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form Submitted";
    $msgcontents = "Name: $name<br>Email: $email<br>Phone Number: $phone<br>Message: $message";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $name <$email_from> \r\n";
    $emailsent = mail($to, $subject, $msgcontents, $headers);
```

Comment: Do you even try looking things up before asking SO? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126

Comment: @Nate Yeah, buddy, I actually do. I searched and tried multiple different suggestions, two of which are pointed out within my question. I am not doing bulk sending. These are single emails. Get a life.

Comment: You say you Google first, but a lot of your posts get flagged as duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

That's because your contact form is sending it to yourself, with the customers email in the from address. You need to send the email differently to yourself, where the customer's email address is not in the "From" field.

You can read more about that here: [The contact us form delimma](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

Comment: I wrote the resource article :)

Comment: @henry I just updated my question. I tried the approach within your article, but it still shows up as spam. I tried two different methods. Both times I am sending it to `contact`. However, I tried making it from `contact` and then `send_to` ... both emails on my server. Am I grasping this concept?

Comment: You're code looks right now, since the TO an FROM are the same, does your SPF record have your IP address in it?

Comment: @Henry Sorry I just noticed you responded. What does SPF stand for? Within my code I am not pulling the IP address. Even if I change `$email_from`'s email to `hello@xxx.com` it still sends it to spam.

Comment: [Sender Policy Framework](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/spfrecords/) - Set one up if you haven't. It should be something similar to `v=spf1 mx a ~all` which is the most basic setup